# Trouble with Set active cell value - Runtime 438

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a script to import data from a series of Workbooks in a declared folder.
The Workbook may contain multiple sheets as dictated by the values on the "DD Meeting" tab, whereby if the cell value begins with "Code_", there will be no sheet to import from.
I'm trying to create a script that looks for a sheet name based on these values, copies the data, then looks for the next sheet to resume the copy job.
I can copy from the first sheet fine, however the script then has trouble searching for the next sheet name using an activecell instead of the declaring a specific cell (I need to offset hence can't name the cell).

This works:

```
Set wsData = wb.Sheets(Worksheets("DD Meeting").Range("D6").Value)
```

This doesnt:

```
Set wsData = wb.Sheets(Worksheets("DD Meeting").ActiveCell.Value)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
Sub ImportInfo()
Dim sPath As String 'path of folder containing info
Dim sFileName As String '
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet 'worksheet to paste data to in this workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet 'sheet with data to copy
Dim wb As Workbook 'workbooks to loop thorugh
Dim nr As Long 'next row to add the data



'Get the worksheet to add the info to
Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'first row is 2
nr = 2

sPath = "C:\Users\sthorley\Downloads\Test\" '[COLOR=#ff0000][B]Change as required[/B][/COLOR]

sFileName = Dir(sPath & "*.xlsm")

Do While sFileName <> ""
    'open workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    wb.Sheets(Worksheets("DD Meeting").Range("D6").Value).Activate
    
    'get the sheet to copy from
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets(Worksheets("DD Meeting").Range("D6").Value)
    Worksheets("DD Meeting").Select
    Worksheets("DD Meeting").Range("D6").Select
    
    
    'get the data
    
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "*Code*"
    
    
    
    wsSummary.Range("A" & nr).Value = wsData.Range("B5").Value
    wsSummary.Range("B" & nr).Value = wsData.Range("B3").Value
    wsSummary.Range("C" & nr).Value = sFileName
    
    wsData.Activate
    
   wsData.Range("A5").Select
    ' Summary Key Points
    wsData.Cells.Find(What:="Summary/Key points", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      
      wsSummary.Range("D" & nr).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(2).Value
    
     
    
    
    
    'get next row
    nr = nr + 1
    
    Worksheets("DD Meeting").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    'get the sheet to copy from
    
  Set wsData = Nothing
  Set wsData = wb.Sheets(Worksheets("DD Meeting").ActiveCell.Value)


    Loop
    
    'close the workbook
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    'get next workbook name
    sFileName = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveCell already encompasses a worksheet the active sheet.  if you want a specific sheet then you need to make sure the correct sheet is active: `Worksheets("DD Meeting").Activate` and then: `Set wsData = wb.Sheets(ActiveCell.Value)`

Comment: Thanks for the help but this gives me runtime error 9: subscript out of range

Comment: It's not clear which workbook "DD meeting" is in?